# Android Encrypt/Decrypt ArrayList<LinkedHashMap> to String

Tags: android, encryption, arraylist

So I'm using the code below for encrypting/decrypting string values that can be stored in the device preferences but I know need to add a method for encrypting/decrypting an ArrayList that can also be stored in the preferences as well (so I'm guessing the encryption needs to convert the arraylist to a string and then the decryption needs to convert that string back to the arraylist). Since I'm pretty new to Android/Java I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this so any help would be appreciated.

```
public String encrypt(String key, String data) {
    if (key == null || data == null)
        return null;
    try {
        DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes(charsetName));
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
        byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes(charsetName);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(dataBytes), base64Mode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public String decrypt(String key, String data) {
    if (key == null || data == null)
        return null;
    try {
        byte[] dataBytes = Base64.decode(data, base64Mode);
        DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes(charsetName));
        SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] dataBytesDecrypted = (cipher.doFinal(dataBytes));
        return new String(dataBytesDecrypted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's exactly the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialize the `ArrayList<LinkedHashMap>` to Json before sending the input to `encrypt()`

```
public static String ArrayListToString(ArrayList<LinkedHashMap> list) {
    Gson serializer = new Gson();
    return serializer.toJson(list);
}
```

then do deserializing after decrypting.

You need to reference [Google-Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) in your project.

Comment: Came here to write this, but as a side note I'd recommend GSON be a static constant since it's heavier to instantiate.

You'll also want to read up on serializing and deserializing ArrayLists as they require a TypeToken, at least for deserializing.

Comment: Thanks both, I'll look into both areas right now and see if I can get that to work